# How to populate a table with results from a while function

Tags: replacement, list-manipulation, infinite-loop

Does anybody know how to save the intermediate results inside a while function in a table?
Here is my code. I would like to save the x,y,counter values in a table in every step that while takes. Thank you!

```
counter = 0;
While[counter < 5,
 counter = counter + 1;
 sol = NSolve[{2 x + y - counter == 0, 
    3 y + 5 x - 2 counter == 0}, {x, y}];
 ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
counter = 0;
sol = {};
While[counter < 5, counter = counter + 1;
 AppendTo[sol, Flatten[{counter, {x, y} /. 
  NSolve[{2 x + y - counter == 0, 3 y + 5 x - 2 counter == 0}, {x,  y}]}]]]

sol
```

> {{1, 1., -1.}, {2, 2., -2.}, {3, 3., -3.}, {4, 4., -4.}, {5, 5., -5.}}

or

```
counter = 0;
sol2 = ConstantArray[0, 5];
While[counter < 5, counter = counter + 1;
 sol2[[counter]] = Flatten@{counter, {x, y} /. 
     NSolve[{2 x + y - counter == 0, 3 y + 5 x - 2 counter == 0}, {x, y}]}]
sol2
```

> {{1, 1., -1.}, {2, 2., -2.}, {3, 3., -3.}, {4, 4., -4.}, {5, 5., -5.}}

Answer (score 7):

Use `Sow` and `Reap` :

```
counter = 0;
Reap @ While[counter < 5, counter = counter + 1;
  sol = NSolve[{2 x + y - counter == 0, 
     3 y + 5 x - 2 counter == 0}, {x, y}];
  Sow[{x, y, counter} /. sol]]
```

Answer (score 4):

I think other answer take your question too literally. You do not really need `While`. IMHO *Mathematica* way of solving this is to use `Table`.

Assuming, that your equation always gives a single solution:

```
Table[
  {x, y, counter} /. 
   First@NSolve[{2 x + y - counter == 0, 
      3 y + 5 x - 2 counter == 0}, {x, y}], {counter, 5}] // TableForm
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To reach the same end, as you mentioned `Table` (a digression: if you know Python, you can compare Wolfram's `Table` with its [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which is attached with more conciseness and readability.), the most direct method is just to use it:

```
Table[
      Append[
             NSolve[{2 x + y - counter == 0, 3 y + 5 x - 2 counter == 0}, {x, y}],
             counter
            ], 
      {counter, 4}
     ]
```

> {
>      {{x -> 1., y -> -1.}, 1}, {{x -> 2., y -> -2.}, 2},
>      {{x -> 3., y -> -3.}, 3}, {{x -> 4., y -> -4.}, 4}
>     }

Comment: Using `Append` you abuse the list of solutions from `NSolve`. I would make a `{NSolve,counter}` instead of `Append[NSolve,counter]`.